# Unable to select image using custom image field type

Tags: plugins, custom-field

I'm using the [advanced custom field plugin](http://plugins.elliotcondon.com/advanced-custom-fields/) and having a bit of trouble when using the image field type. (I'm not sure if this relates to the plugin that much actually!).

When inserting an image instead of the option to select it I only have the option to insert it into post, which tries to insert the image into a wysiwyg. I only get the option to select image if I first insert it into post then delete it from the wysiwyg, then click choose image again and find it in the media gallery.

Is there any workarounds/plugins to allow me to select the image straight away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Verve Meta Boxes](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/verve-meta-boxes/) plugin of if you are up to coding yourself a metabox then you can use [**this class**](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/p/meta-box-script-for-wordpress.html) which does most of the work for you.

Comment: Cheers, are there any alternatives? The reason being that this is a problem on several sites I have and I don't want to have to rebuild things. I almost feel like I need something to adjust the image upload area to select the images better.